# Changeset Management Tools?

Tags: change-set, release

I am looking if there is any “change set management” tool out there.
I am cannot use a CI/CD and version control system due to the company policy, so I am searching for a program that can help me organize the changes besides excel spreadsheets.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend (we are a user of) [Gearset](https://gearset.com/product/deployments?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIkqKxg6b15AIVoR6tBh2ZqASrEAAYASAAEgL20_D_BwE). It works great for org-org (you don't have to use source control although that is well-supported too).

Pricing is reasonable and it supports admins and developers equally well.

Answer (score 1):

Joe,

Check out our product Snapshot (https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016YhyEAE). We can do anything that Changesets can (change and release management) without the need for Excel spreadsheets. We also do Org Optimization + Data Migration + Org documentation.

Good luck!

Sridhar